# How to get Result for RecyclerView using Spinner in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

Hello can you guys help me?

I am doing an apps where it will display premises. User also can filtered it using Spinner to ease their searching. But i've trouble to filter the Spinner and the result seems can't be display in the RecyclerView

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    EditText txtPremiseSearch = findViewById(R.id.txtPremiseSearch);
    RecyclerView rcvPremise = findViewById(R.id.rcvPremises);
    Spinner spnCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnCategory);

    //Spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.premise_type));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnCategory.setAdapter(adapter);

    spnCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //txtPremiseSearch.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    //Dummy list of premises
    Vector<Premises> premises = new Vector<>();
    Premises premises1 = new Premises(), premises2 = new Premises(), premises3 = new Premises();

    premises1.setPremiseID("001");
    premises1.setName("Medan Selera Presint 8");
    premises1.setRole("Restaurant");

    premises2.setPremiseID("002");
    premises2.setName("Old Precint Cafe");
    premises2.setRole("Cafe");

    premises3.setPremiseID("003");
    premises3.setName("Gloria Jean's Cafe");
    premises3.setRole("Cafe");

    premises.add(premises1);
    premises.add(premises2);
    premises.add(premises3);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome " + intent.getStringExtra("name") + " to the Administration module!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    rcvPremise.setAdapter(new PremisesAdapter(this, premises));
    rcvPremise.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfXR6.png)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  But you should call setAdaper after setLayoutManager not before.

Comment: Means, the setadapter for the Spinner should be call after the setLayoutManager for the RecyclerView is it?

Comment: @ADM i want the user can filter the recyclerview using Spinner but unfortunately after user filter it, it doesn't effect the recyclerview sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's cause the recycler view doesn't update yet. Try to run setLayoutManager b4 the setAdapter, then declare again adapter and set adapter, when user click on the selected item on spinner

Comment: already change it but still when i choose any option in the spinner, it doesn’t display the result filter based on the spinner in the RecyclerView. Any solution on how to make it display the filter result from the spinner in RecyclerView?

Comment: u can use if else, or switch, like   if(userSelected.equals("001") {  rcvPremise.setAdapter(new PremisesAdapter(this, premises1)); }